# ReactJs DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is that the DateRangePicker it is messing with highlighting the last chosen filter in list.

For example look in the following picture:

[image]

As you can see i have choose Last 15 Minutes option.

```
 <DateRangePicker
     onApply={this.handleDatePicker}
     showDropdowns
     showCustomRangeLabel
     showWeekNumbers
     startDate={moment(this.state.datetimeFrom)}
     endDate={moment(this.state.datetimeTo)}
     timePicker
     timePicker24Hour
     timePickerSeconds
     ranges={DATEPICKER_RANGES }
     locale={DATEPICKER_LOCALE}
```

This is the component into jsx file.

Comment: Can you give me a codesandbox to reproduce this error?

Comment: I would assume that given you are storing the `datetimeFrom` and `datetimeTo` dates in the state, they are immediately out of date (and no longer actually the last 15 minutes) by the time the component renders. I don't know this component, but can you select a range rather than passing in the start/end?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito i tried to make as i have it into my project since i cannot share all details of app and i am very new to ReactJs. Please find that in following link https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-satoshi-sugoy

Comment: @DBS I have played with these variables also but it is so strange, it should be be default working properly since in Jquery works fine.